# HTTPURLResponse.localizedString(forStatusCode:) not in development language

Tags: ios, swift, localized, nshttpurlresponse

I am making an iOS app, and I have this problem.

- My app most be only in Spanish, so i changed the development language (in the hard way, changing the `developmentRegion = es;` inside the the `project.pbxproj` and changing the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion=es` in the `Info.plist`)
- I also add a `Localizable.strings` to my only language (es) to have all the `Strings` inside one document. And all my `NSLocalizedStrings` works fine

The problem comes out when i use the function `HTTPURLResponse.localizedString(forStatusCode:)`
it only give me back `Strings` in English. Previously works fine, but after added the `Localizable.string` don't work well anymore

Any help to bring back the `Strings` to Spanish??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the correct approach.

You don't need to localise low level network error as:

- are generally useless to final user
- are handy to develop, not to be shown (you can eventually log them..)
- when you got a code, change it in a readable generic message, and THEN localise it.

For III point:

```
final private func downloadMyData(){

guard let myURL = URL(string: "__https://ingconti.com/wrongurl") else{

    return
}

let session = URLSession.shared

let task = session.dataTask(with: myURL) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

    // session cannot be created...
       if let error = error  {
            self.manageLowLevel(error: error)
            return
        }

    var statusCode: Int = 0
    if let httpResponse : HTTPURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
        statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
    }

    if 200 ... 299 ~= statusCode {
        self.parse(data: data)
    }else{
        self.manageHTTPError(code: statusCode, data: data)
    }
}


task.resume()
```

}

If you got a BIG error (for example in my code I used a wrong prefix, "__https")
You will get _code = -1022,

and You can manage this way:

```
 final private func manageLowLevel(error: Error){
        #if DEBUG
        print(error)
        #endif
        var msg = ""
        let code = error._code
        switch code {
        case -1002:
            msg = localized("GENERIC_NETWORK_ERR")
        default:
            msg = localized("GENERIC_NETWORK_ERR")
        }

        // display msg... (on MAIN THREAD...)
    }



    func localized(_ msg: String)->String{
        let s = NSLocalizedString(msg, comment : "")
        return s
    }
```

Where You can mask out message to final user and make it more general (and localised using a convenience function "localized")

For HTTP error (for example not found resource... i.e. "https://ingconti.com/wrongurl") You will get error 404 in http/s.

So you can do similar:

final private func manageHTTPError(code: Int, data : Data?){
        guard let data = data else{
            return
        }

```
    #if DEBUG
    if let s = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){
        print(s)
    }else{
        if let s = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii){
            print(s)
        }
    }
    #endif

    var msg = ""
    switch code {
    case 404:
        msg = localized("NETWORK_CODE_404")
    default:
        msg = localized("GENERIC_NETWORK_ERR")
    }

    // display msg...
}
```

Or even merged toghether.

(string s in

#if DEBUG
        if let s = .....

will show server error, and again do not show to user...)

to sum up:
so not show low level error, see gentle message, so for example in you localized strings You can have:

"GENERIC_NETWORK_ERR"            = "Network error";
"NETWORK_CODE_404".              = "Network error (no data)";

and in spanish...

"GENERIC_NETWORK_ERR"            = "error de red ";
...

Hope it can help.

Comment: I strongly disagree. Those HTTP Status related error messages are very helpful. If the user does not understand, he can ask someone else and he will be pointing into the right direction. Just imagine the difference between 4xx and 5xx status codes. 4xx = you have done something wrong. 5xx = the service has done something wrong.

Comment: Anyway, this question was not about the usefulness of those messages but about how to get the localized version from iOS APIs.