# Why is the Data object passed to the completionHandler empty in `func dataTask(with request:, completionHandler:`?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, rest

To make a network request, I'm using:

`session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in...`

I'm trying to specifically handle different cases of getting a `400` response from the server. Meaning, I'm purposely trying to have failing requests, whose responses are `400` errors. `error` is `nil`, as expected.

The data passed into the closure is always empty, and `response.status.localizedDescription` just says "bad request".

On the backend, we're able to see which error was actually thrown, but not on the client.

How can I see the details of the failed request's response? For example, "Bad Request: email is already in use".

Happy to expand or clarify as needed.

Comment: "error is nil as expected" --> if you're purposefully hitting an error case, `error` should not be nil. `data` should be nil in an error scenario.  I would expect to get the details of the error from the `error.localizedDescription`.

Comment: @wilc0 In this request, `error` is `nil`, and `data` is `0 bytes`? I wouldn't expect a server error, because it's a client error - a bad request. Does that make my issue clearer?

Comment: Any http request with a status code that does not equal `2xx` will result in `data` being nil or 0 bytes and `response` containing the status code and a localizedString of that status code (which is not customizable as far as I can tell). To add any additional details to the error, you will have to add a custom http header that contains some more information: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpurlresponse/1417930-allheaderfields

Comment: Here are a few related questions that show how you can parse through the various objects that are returned in the completionHandler: 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22208113/4608154 and 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55205384/4608154